# react native - getting state from storage on before render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise

I am using `react-native-simple-store`, trying to read the value form the storage.

defined this in `constructor`:

```
this.checkIfTermsAgreedTo = this.checkIfTermsAgreedTo.bind(this);
```

Using this function

```
checkIfTermsAgreedTo(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => { 
      return store.get('agreed');
    })
    .then(agreed =>{
      console.log(agreed); --> This line is never reached
      console.log((agreed.terms == "YES") ? "AGREED!" : "Not agreed....");
      return agreed;
    })
  }
```

Using the Promise as follows in `componentWillMount`:

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.checkIfTermsAgreedTo().then(agreed=>{
      this.setState({agreed:(agreed.terms == "YES")});
    })
      .catch(()=>{
        console.log("CATCH: Agreed, probably not found");
        this.setState({agreed:{terms:"NO"}})}
      );  
  }
```

The designated line is never reached. (in checkIfTermsAgreedTo, under "then").
What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just resolve your output in the first promise.

```
checkIfTermsAgreedTo(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => { 
      resolve(store.get('agreed'));
    })
    .then(agreed =>{
      console.log(agreed); --> This line is never reached
      console.log((agreed.terms == "YES") ? "AGREED!" : "Not agreed....");
      return agreed;
    })
}
```

When you initialize a `new Promise` with `resolve` and `reject` keep in mind that `resolve` and `reject` are nothing but the function blocks that you pass in your `then`. For example.

```js
var i = 100;

var k = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 if(i === 100) 
  resolve("I AM RESOLVED BY YOUR FIRST FUNCTION BLOCK")
 else 
  reject("I AM REJECTED BY YOUR SECOND FUNCTION BLOCK") 
})

// Now when you resolve the promise like below, the `thenable` struct 
// will expect two function blocks or atleast one which are the 
// success(resolve) and error(reject) blocks

resolveBlock = (response) => {
 console.log(response);
}

rejectBlock = (reject) => {
 console.log(reject);
}

k.then(resolveBlock, rejectBlock);

// I AM RESOLVED BY YOUR FIRST FUNCTION BLOCK

// OR IT CAN BE WRITTEN AS BELOW WHICH IS THE USUAL NORM
// k.then((response) => {
//  console.log(response);
// }, (reject) => {
//  console.log(reject);
// })
```

This is one of the best guides for getting started / revising `Promises` https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises#whats-all-the-fuss-about

Comment: Sweet! It works. Why not resolve the last one too, then?

Comment: Will add the reason in about 10 mins. Travelling.

Comment: Happy Traveling!

Comment: Thanks @Nandu Kalidindi!

Comment: So, what are resolve and reject in the first Promise? They are empty objects, also not defined?

Comment: They are the callback functions `resolve` == `resolveBlock` and `reject` == `rejectBlock`. The arguments to `.then` are passed as `resolve` and `reject`.